# Extraction of white pixels from a binary image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a binary image as my input and I have detected the centroid using "region props" and now I want to extract white pixels which are to the right side of the centroid only in MATLAB. How to do it? Any help will be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and sample images.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
% let r_centroid be the centroid's row
[r,c] = find( img == 1 );
gt_idx = find( r > r_centroid );
r( gt_idx ) % print the answer
```